# New TortoiseSVN Certificate Error for LetsEncrypt signed server

Tags: ssl, certificate, svn, tortoise-svn, letsencrypt

Related to this old question from 2011, but a new problem:

[Tortoise SVN Error Validating Server Certificate](https://superuser.com/questions/275590)

We have an SVN server that has a certificate that is signed by LetsEncrypt.

Until this week, that has been fine in TortoiseSVN as well as every other SVN client and browser we use.

However, yesterday some versions (1.14.1, at least) of TortoiseSVN started issuing certificate warnings for the SVN server. All browsers on the same machines are still perfectly happy with the certificate.

We think it is related to the change in the root signing of LetsEncrypt, they did have two different root paths, and one has expired this week.

From the OpenSSL command at this page:

https://howto.lintel.in/check-certificate-information-web-server-using-openssl/

I believe the SVN server is correctly offering the local certificate, the LetsEncrypt intermediate certificate and the "ISRG Root X1" root certificate.

What's really unclear to me is where TortoiseSVN (or I guess more precisely the Apache SVN library it uses) gets its list of root certificates.

It is also unclear (because I don't know what it is using) whether the problem will fix itself with some automatic update to that list of certificates, and whether there is an easy change that users can make to add the ISRG certificate to the valid root certificates (adding an ssl-authority-files setting into the "servers" SVN config file? But where is there likely to be a system file that SVN can be pointed towards to prevent everyone having to download, convert and install the root certificate?).

There is another option in the servers config file "ssl-trust-default-ca", but setting this doesn't seem to make any difference, and it is again not clear where it will be looking for the "system default CAs" on Windows.

Comment: As another strangeness, the behaviour of 1.14.1 seems to vary depending on what previous versions, if any, you have installed. On machines which haven't had any old versions, you get the certificate error, but on some machines which have had 1.10.5 and/or 1.11.0 installed then whatever is different about the root certificates is remembered, even across and uninstall/reboot/reinstall

Comment: What is the server actually offering? How did you check, and are you sure that it is not still offering the version of "ISRG Root X1" that was cross-signed by DST X3? Normally clients _do not_ receive the list of root certificates from the server, **especially not from a server that they can't yet verify** -- doing so would completely defeat the point.